# IBM MobileFirst Platform iFix doesnt update the version of MFPF Runtime

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

After applying latest iFix( 8.0.0.0-MFPF-IF201708031112) to the IBM MobileFirst Server 8.0.0 and cordova-mfp-plugin( v8.0.2017072706), MFPF Runtime still shows the older version no (8.0.2017070506). Due to the mismatch of the server runtime version and mfp plugin version we were not able to connect to the server and obtain accessToken in our mobile application.

**Below is the version info log captured from server messages.log file.**

[8/9/17 10:26:02:750 EDT] 00000025     com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.logging.ServerInfoLog       I

**MFP version: 8.0.0.00-20170803-1112**

**MFPF runtime version: 8.0.2017070506**

Running on server: Liberty, version:8.5.5.8. Running on premise

Running OS: Windows Server 2012 R2, version: 6.3

Java: IBM Corporation, version: 1.7.0

DB name: DB2/NT64, DB version: SQL10058

**Application Log:**

08-08 20:48:40.935 19080-19112/com.xxxxx E/null: >> Failed to connect to MobileFirst Server{"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request","responseText":"{\"**server_version**\":\"**8.0.2017070506**\", **"errorCode\":\"PROTOCOL_MISMATCH_ERROR\"**,\"errorMsg\":**"There is a mismatch between the SDK versions used for this application. If you upgraded the SDK, please create a new application version.\"**}","errorMsg":"There is a mismatch between the SDK versions used for this application. If you upgraded the SDK, please create a new application version.","errorCode":"**PROTOCOL_MISMATCH_ERROR**"}

08-08 20:48:40.950 19080-19112/com.xxxxx E/null: Fatal error - Client was unable to connect to MFP Server

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause of the issue is this -
you had application registrations when your server was at an iFix level prior to February 2017. There were Dynamic app authenticity feature related changes in the February build (details [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/03/09/8-0-ifix-release/)), which does not apply directly to earlier application registrations. Owing to which due to this it is ending up with "Protocol Mistmatch Error".

In order to resolve the issue, increment your application registration version in MFP Operations Console & in your client application. Rebuild the client application and it should connect to the server successfully.